# Unable to connect to the database on mongolab account

Tags: php, mongodb

I have created an account on mongoDB lab and now when I try to connect with this command

```
mongo ds037824.mongolab.com:37824/mydatabase -u rakeshstellen -p stellen@123
```

getting this error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: ds037824.mongolab.com:37824/mydatabase
2015-10-15T10:45:14.185+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 54.198.170.179:37824 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2015-10-15T10:45:14.188+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server ds037824.mongolab.com:37824 (54.198.170.179), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trouble-shooting guide:

http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#help

and if you still have problems after that, email support@mongolab.com and they can help you.

-will

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have tried and I can ping but when I have run the second command getting error connection time out